# SMILES structure of molecule giving error while converting into embedded representation or conformations

Tags: computational-chemistry, rdkit

I am trying to compute the bond angles of all the pairs of bond in a set of molecule from Colontrix dataset. Some of the molecules are showing up error when I am implementing the following.The error says:

**Example:** `Isosorbide 5-nitrate [C1[C@@H]([C@@H]2[C@H](O1)[C@@H](CO2)O[N+](=O)[O-])O]`

**Error:**

```
Value Error: Bad Conformer id.
```

**Code:**

```
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem as Chem

mol_obj = Chem.MolFromSmiles(mol["smiles"])
Chem.EmbedMolecule(mol_obj, randomSeed=42)
conf = mol3d.GetConformer()
```

Comment: Is there a longer stack trace that goes along with the error. That will point to which line in your code (and probably more importantly which line in rdkit) is raising this error.

Comment: @Formal_this I hope my answer solves your question. If yes, please click on the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid renaming modules with existing module names.

For example, in your imports you have renamed `AllChem` as `Chem`. However there is already an existing library called `Chem` in `rdkit`. There is a high chance that this will cause problems for you if you need to use something from the actual "`Chem`" module.

Also it looks like you perhaps have the wrong SMILES for `isosorbide-5-mononitrate`. I got the SMILES from this [website](https://www.medchemexpress.com/Isosorbide-mononitrate.html).

Here is a working code that will resolve your conformer id error:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem

isosorbide_5_mononitrate_smiles = 'O=[N+]([O-])O[C@H]1[C@](OC[C@@H]2O)([H])[C@]2([H])OC1'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(isosorbide_5_mononitrate_smiles)
mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
AllChem.EmbedMolecule(mol, randomSeed=42)
conf = mol.GetConformer()
```

Comment: As you mentioned, the SMILES is garbled. In this case, it's the initial '[' and trailing ']' characters - the SMILES syntax expects [ ] to reflect an individual atom environment. The "import AllChem as Chem" is considered okay - Greg uses it in the RDKit cookbook after all.

Comment: In my opinion aliasing modules with names of already existing modules creates unnecessary confusion.  It also has adds possibility of problems in case one needs to use one of the existing libraries.